# Ho w to resolve 'ERROR: browser_switcher_service.cc' XXX Init() issue in Chrome driver in selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[image]

This error is displaying in VS2019 when try to execute the script on chrome 81 on win 10. Other scripts are executing successfully.

Comment: On debug- this script is executing successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Update your chromedriver.exe or nuget package - worked for me when I just had the same issue.